# Persist HTMLSession in Django

Tags: python, html, django, session

What is the best method of persisting a HTMLSession in Django between different views? I use the request.session to persist some data between views, but I can't find a solution to also persist the HTMLSession. For example, I use requests-html to create a HTMLSession to grab a link, but I have a few more views that will do different things but needs access to the same HTMLSession. Data that I need to persist I store in request.session which is working fine, I just can't figure out how to persist the HTMLSession.

I've tried serializing the HTMLSession, however, further investigation lead to me to realize these should NOT be serializable, and only iterate over the HTMLSession data and serialize those.

Custom class

```
from requests_html import HTML, HTMLSession

class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        session = HTMLSession()
```

views.py

```
def get_item(request):
    foo = Foo()
    request.session['item'] = 'test'
    return HttpResponse('test')

# Foo() initializes the HTMLSession
# Need to use that same session between each view

def show_item(request):
    item = request.session['item']
    return HttpResponse('test')
```

Code above doesn't make sense, just trying to show what I'm trying to achieve. Is this possible? Or am I completely misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 0):

My solution in case anyone has any similar issue, although probably not the best:

```
my_dynamic_dict = {}

my_dynamic_dict['{}'.format(dynamic_key)] = test
```

Use a dict to store the instance of a class which contains the HTMLSession which I can retrieve again later.